# AWS CDK: deploy error "Error reason: EXACTLY_ONE_CONDITION_REQUIRED, field: MANAGED_RULE_GROUP_CONFIG, parameter: ManagedRuleGroupConfig"

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, web-application-firewall

below environment

- node-js: 16.16.0
- aws-cdk: 2.41.0

When I just tried `cdk deploy` it gives me the following error:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Error reason: EXACTLY_ONE_CONDITION_REQUIRED, field: MANAGED_RULE_GROUP_CONFIG, parameter: ManagedRuleGroupConfig (Service: Wafv2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: f35c1b88-57f9-420b-9f
db-3e6e99aefb8d, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: f9a83934-9d2b-9b52-0f97-ebf49c15c42c, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

below my source code

```html
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as wafv2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-wafv2';

export class CdkWorkshopStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // defines an AWS WAFv2 WebACL resource
    const webACL = new wafv2.CfnWebACL(this, 'WebACL', {
      defaultAction: {
        block: {},
      },
      scope: 'REGIONAL',
      name: 'waf-sample',
      description: 'this is a test',
      visibilityConfig: {
        cloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true,
        metricName: 'WebACL',
        sampledRequestsEnabled: true
      },
      rules: [
        {
          priority: 9,
          name: 'AWS-AWSManagedRulesATPRuleSet',
          statement: {
            managedRuleGroupStatement: {
              name: 'AWSManagedRulesATPRuleSet',
              vendorName: 'AWS',
              managedRuleGroupConfigs: [{
                loginPath: '/loginPath',        
                payloadType: 'JSON',
                usernameField: {
                  identifier: '/form/username', 
                },
                passwordField: {
                  identifier: '/form/password',
                },
              }],
            }
          },
          overrideAction: { none: {} },
          visibilityConfig: {
            cloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true,
            metricName: 'AWS-AWSManagedRulesATPRuleSet',
            sampledRequestsEnabled: true
          }
        },
      ],
    });
  }
}
```

I know that 'managedRuleGroupConfigs' is the cause.
But i don't know what exactly is wrong.

I tried deploying with `managedRuleGroupConfigs.loginPath` ,then the following error.

```
 CdkWorkshopStack failed: Error: The stack named CdkWorkshopStack failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Error reason: A required field is missing from the parameter., field: MANAGED_RULE_SET_STATEMENT, parameter: null (Service: Wafv2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 3aa6ce31-b677-4058-9ef3-158f19b6022e, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: c569740d-4f74-f11d-4b8a-a1fe7431ab19, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

I just need your knowledge.